# Git CLI: Style output

Tags: git, command-line-interface, devops

I'm a junior developer so please forgive me if this is a nooby question. I'm not  even sure this is possible but here goes.

So, lets say I am going to push something in using the CLI for Git. I would use:

```
$ git push
```

Sometimes, I will get an error message along the lines of:

> fatal: The current branch release/v2.37 has no upstream branch.
>   To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

However I seem to miss this more often than not and its because its small black text on a white background.

I want to be able to style the word 'fatal' with a red background and white text. Is this possible, if so how?

Comment: I don't think that's easily possible. But couldn't you just adjust your terminal settings to increase the font size and maybe use another color theme to generally increase the readability of its contents?